# how to get permission from website to use in android WebView

Tags: android, webview, permissions, google-play

i own a website and i want to convert my website in android application using web view but as per play store policy i m not able to publish my app on the play store now my main question how can i add get  permission from web site to use in web View and publish on the play store.
Thanx in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What issue are you facing on playstore? text?

Answer (score 0):

**Provide advance notice to the Google Play App Review team**

You need to give the trust them as you are owner of your website.

Go through this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/adv_note) to submit documents